# iterate through datareader/datatable within loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

I am dynamically building a navbar based upon security permissions grabbed from a database.  The database lookup includes the page name.  Initially I was using a datareader and doing the below:

```
SqlDataReader SRmenu = sqlCMD.ExecuteReader();
HtmlGenericControl liToAdd;
if (SRmenu.HasRows)
{
    while (SRmenu.Read())
    {
        liToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        MainUL1.Controls.Add(liToAdd);
        HtmlGenericControl addpage = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        addpage.Attributes.Add("href", Convert.ToString(SRmenu["PageName"]));
        addpage.InnerText = Convert.ToString(SRmenu["Name"]);
        liToAdd.Controls.Add(addpage);
    }
}
SRmenu.Close();
conn.Close();
```

This worked perfectly fine until I wanted to add in possible drop down menu's (for sections that have more than one page that the person has access).  My updated code is below

```
if (SRmenu.HasRows)
            {
                while (SRmenu.Read())
                {
                    LoopCount = LoopCount + 1;
                    Int32 AppCount = Convert.ToInt32(SRmenu["AppCount"]);
                    if (AppCount > 1)
                    {
                        Int32 ApplicationID = Convert.ToInt32(SRmenu["ApplicationID"]);
                        Int32 ApplicationID2 = Convert.ToInt32(SRmenu["ApplicationID"]);
                        liToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                        liToAdd.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown");
                        MainUL1.Controls.Add(liToAdd);

                        HtmlGenericControl addhref = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                        addhref.Attributes.Add("href", Convert.ToString(SRmenu["PageName"]));
                        addhref.InnerText = Convert.ToString(SRmenu["Name"]);
                        liToAdd.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-toggle");
                        addhref.Attributes.Add("data-toggle", "dropdown");
                        liToAdd.Controls.Add(addhref);

                        HtmlGenericControl addspan = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
                        addspan.Attributes.Add("class", "caret");
                        addhref.Controls.Add(addspan);

                        HtmlGenericControl addUL = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");
                        addUL.Attributes.Add("class", "dropdown-menu");
                        liToAdd.Controls.Add(addUL);

                        while (ApplicationID == ApplicationID2)
                        {
                            HtmlGenericControl addDropDown = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                            addUL.Controls.Add(addDropDown);
                            HtmlGenericControl addpage = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                            addpage.Attributes.Add("href", Convert.ToString(SRmenu["PageName"]));
                            addpage.InnerText = Convert.ToString(SRmenu["Name"]);
                            addDropDown.Controls.Add(addpage);
                            SRmenu.Read();
                            if (LoopCount < FieldCount)
                            { ApplicationID2 = Convert.ToInt32(SRmenu["ApplicationID"]); }
                            else
                            { ApplicationID2 = 0; }
                            LoopCount = LoopCount + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        liToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                        MainUL1.Controls.Add(liToAdd);
                        HtmlGenericControl addpage = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
                        addpage.Attributes.Add("href", Convert.ToString(SRmenu["PageName"]));
                        addpage.InnerText = Convert.ToString(SRmenu["Name"]);
                        liToAdd.Controls.Add(addpage);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Where I am running into the issue is adding in a loop within the READ() loop.  Currently I am trying to use the While (ApplicationID == ApplicationID2) loop and this is letting me get the 1st value but not the 2nd (there are only two pages currently that fall within the same ApplicationID and they are the last two records in my Read() loop) - the issue is that the second value never makes it into the drop down.

When I run it in debug it does not go through a second loop, it hits the 'if (SRmenu.HasRows)' it fails to find additional rows so it exists the loop - if I comment out the entire IF/ELSE and go back to my original code it does see all of the expected pages so the data is present.

I know how I would accomplish this in classic ASP but am struggling to find a similar solution in C#/ASP.NET.  What I would have done in classic is something like

```
RSMenu.open
do while not RSMenu.EoF
    if PageCount>1 then
      <code for drop down segment>
      do while count < PageCount
         <LI HTML Code>
         RSMenu.MoveNext
      loop
    else
        <LI HTML Code>
    end if
    RSMenu.MoveNext
loop
```

Edits

1. updated comment about FOR loop
2. Removed reference to the FOR loop.  it isn't something I was using and after re-reading feel it was not relevant towards my question.  It was listed as another method considered but it did not appear to offer a resolution to the above issue.
3. Looks like NextResult(); is the wrong command, that loops through a batch of commands it does not iterate to the next record in that Read set - so what I am trying to figure out is HOW to do that.
4. Apparently Read() iterates to the next record.  The 'HasRows' method wasn't working for testing if it STILL had rows so I added in a FieldCount prior to the loop and a LoopCount within.  That is working.

Comment: Your "for" loop at the end *does* get every value from the row (reader.GetValue(i) gets the value of the i'th column of the current row).

Comment: @David_001 - Sorry I meant to say it doesn't let me iterate through the rows.  Will update.

Comment: @David_001 I had mentioned the FOR loop as another solution I had considered but it did not appear that it would function differently from what I was doing.  After reading over my post I felt it was ancillary information that was not relevant (since I was not currently using it and I had not gone into other methods tried/considered).

Comment: I found a bit of my issue, the NextResult(); command does not iterate through the current READ(), it goes to the next dataset if you are executing a batch of records.  So my core issue is how can I iterate through a read record without going back up to the top of the loop.  Or sans that can I redo my HTML methods to move them partially outside of the loop.

Comment: Not related to your issue - but it is usually worthwhile to have strongly typed data model based on POC rather then fetching values directly from db to control tree. Also caching is handy (you don't need to query db for navigation for every single request).

Answer (score 0):

I made final edits above to include but the issue is I was trying to use .NEXTRESULT() which is intended for iterating through a batch of queries.  .READ() will iterate to the next record.

I also found the .HASROWS only checks if the reader has, not if there are records still left.  So I added in a fieldcount prior to the read() starting and loop count.

I feel like there is a better way to do this and may see about pulling the HTML declarations outside of the loop then seeing if I can properly add to them from inside - but right now this is working.